# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{3})$.

This question basically boils down to showing that $\sqrt{3}-\sqrt[3]{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3})$ since if so, then

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}) \ni \frac{1}{2} [(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt[3]{3})+ (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3})]= \sqrt{3}$$
and
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}) \ni \frac{-1}{2} [(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt[3]{3})- (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3})]= \sqrt[3]{3}$$.

I was thinking it was simple (using conjugates?) but I’m struggling to show it. Any hints? Thank you!

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745628/show-that-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt35-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt35?rq=1) and repeat the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{3}$, then we have
$(u-\sqrt{3})^{3}=3\Leftrightarrow u^3-3\sqrt{3}u^2+9u-3\sqrt{3}=3$

So $\sqrt{3}=\dfrac{u^{3}+9u-3}{3u^2+3}\in \mathbb{Q}(u)$ and $\sqrt[3]{3}=u-\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(u)$

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{3})\subset \mathbb{Q}(u)$.

Comment: Another way: find the irreducible polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ by using Esenstein Criterion, and found that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=6=[ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]$.

Comment: This works. Thank you! The irreducible polynomial is $x^6-9x^4-6x^3+27x^2-54x-18$ so Eisenstein Criterion can’t be applied as $3^2 \mid 18$, so I was looking for a simpler method.